# Error with Unarchiving SKEmitterNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to add explosion after i shoot object i am using this code to make the method

```
func addExplosion (position : CGPoint) -> CGPoint

    {

    let explosionPath : NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MyParticle", ofType: "sks")!

    let explosion : SKEmitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(explosionPath)

    explosion.position = position;
    self.addChild(explosion)

    let removeExplosion : SKAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5) , SKAction.removeFromParent()]);

    explosion.runAction(removeExplosion);

    }
```

But i have problem with

```
let explosion : SKEmitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(explosionPath)
```

Xcode gives notice to fix-it by adding `as String` after `explosionPath`to become like this `explosionPath as String` but after that it gives another error

```
'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'SKEmitterNode'
```

I cant figure out what the problem any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unarchiveObjectWithFile` returns an `AnyObject?`. Change

```
let explosion : SKEmitterNode = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(explosionPath)
```

to

```
let explosion = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(explosionPath) as! SKEmitterNode
```

This forces down casting to a `SKEmitterNode`.